# convert string to base convert 62

Tags: php, laravel, url-shortener

I was trying to make a URL shortener. Where the give url needs to convert to base 62

I have converted the URL in following but it convert it to random number like `0` or `1sromm8` or  `2gs0ygibs`

```
  base_convert($shortener->full_url, 10, 36);
```

How do i convert it to base62 so that every time 5 characters unique name generated.

Comment: `base_convert()` is for numbers, not strings.

Comment: Sure you don't mean base64?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting a number base 10 to base 62 (a-zA-Z0-9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964197/converting-a-number-base-10-to-base-62-a-za-z0-9)

Comment: I want to convert URL to base 62? Is it possible?

Comment: Is there anything not working with that single line of code? If yes, wht have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**I use this customized function to convert String to base62 String**

```
function b62e($str) {
    if(mb_check_encoding($str, 'ASCII')) {
        $out = '';
        $len = strlen($str);
        for($i=0; $i<$len; $i+=8) {
            $chunk = substr($str, $i, 8);
            $outlen = ceil( strlen($chunk)*8/6 );// 8bit/char in, 6bits/char out, round up
            $hex = bin2hex($chunk);// gmp won't convert from binary, so go via hex
            $raw = gmp_strval(gmp_init(ltrim($hex, '0'), 16), 62);// gmp doesn't like leading 0s
            $out .= str_pad($raw, $outlen, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        return $out;
    }
    return false;// unicode chars not supported
}



function b62d($str) {
    if(mb_check_encoding($str, 'ASCII')) {
        $out = '';
        $len = strlen($str);
        for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i+=11) {
            $chunk = substr($str, $i, 11);
            $outlen = floor( strlen($chunk)*6/8 );// 6bit/char in, 8bits/char out, round down
            $raw = gmp_strval(gmp_init(ltrim($chunk, '0'), 62), 16);// gmp doesn't like leading 0s
            $pad = str_pad($raw, $outlen * 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);// double output length as as we're going via hex (4bits/char)
            $out .= pack('H*', $pad);// same as hex2bin
        }
        return $out;
    }
    return false;// unicode chars not supported
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EBWIP)

All credits go to [Marcus Bointon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333340/synchro), Thanks to [Flash Thunder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033392/12912762) answer

---

**May you also use obfuscator to prevent users decode variables**

```
function obf62rep($which){// make array before translate string
    $rep    = [];
    $str1   = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $str2   = 'GHIJKLMNqrstuvwx01OPQRSTUVWXYZhijklmnop23456789abcdefgyzABCDEF';
    if($which){// while obfuscate from-->to
        $fr = str_split($str1);
        $to = $str2;
    }else{// while de-obfuscate to-->from
        $fr = str_split($str2);
        $to = $str1;
    }
    foreach($fr as $k=>$v){// make array tr-->to
        $rep[$v] = $to[$k];
    }
    return $rep;
}

function obf62e($str){return strtr($str,obf62rep(1));}// translate string = obf
function obf62d($str){return strtr($str,obf62rep(0));}// translate back = deobf
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/r2DsY)

---

**And then make it more simple to use, like**

```
function ob62e($str){return obf62e(b62e($str));}// encode base62 + obfuscate
function ob62d($str){return b62d(obf62d($str));}// decode base62 + deobfuscate
```

Sample usage

```
echo ob62e('test');

$name = ob62e('jhon');
```